# How to programmatically update node title?

Tags: nodes

I would like to programmatically update some fields including the title of a node, when this node is saved.
To do so I am using a hook

```
function MY_MODULE_node_update($node) {
    $node->title = "Something new an beautiful";
    $node->filed_what_ever = "Something";
    field_attach_update('node', $node);
}
```

The problem is, that the title is not updated, I assume, that's because of the fact it isn't a field an the Drupal sense.
But I can not use

```
node_save($node);
```

instead, because that brings me in an infinite loop: the function hook_node_update() is called by the function node_save()... So what would be a clean why to do this?

Comment: You should probably use a hook that gets called earlier in the node updating process. I think adding a custom submit handler in a hook_form_alter(), that changes the node title before save, might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you have to use [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7).

It's called before saving the node to the database. (both new nodes and edits). 
Note that you must make sure that you are saving sanitized and formatted data.

Comment: Does that mean, with hook_node_presave() I just can set or alter the fields as I wish, and than they will be saved without having to call field_attach_update() or node_save() again?

Comment: exactly! You don't need to return the node. it will be passed by reference so go ahead and make the changes.

Comment: The only way to change programmatically the node title is in the hook_node_presave?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer with the context of original question about using a hook_node_update, you will have to use the presave hook or save the node yourself.